# Recognize randomly typed gibberish

Tags: gratis, validation

I have a web form that requires people to enter an email address.
I don't want to implement an email verification system because it would be cumbersome for the user.

30% of my visitors just type random characters and an email host, for instance:

- `asdasdas@gmail.com`
- `1243142314234@gmail.com`
- `qwreettryiuop@gmail.com`

Looking at a QWERTY keyboard and all other keyboards in circulation, I would say there is 99% probably that `asdasdas@gmail.com` is a fake address.
I am looking for a library or program or web service that would estimate this probability for me.

Requirement:

- Free
- Takes an [string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local_part) like `asdasdas` and returns a probability
- Based on QWERTY, bonus for other keyboards and IME of the world
- Not based on dictionary comparizon

Comment: I don't think the question is "wrong", but your goal "I don't want to implement an email verification system because it would be cumbersome for the user" will lead you into all sorts of problems. The amount of effort you spend, for probably no gain at all (these users are saving a few seconds time by bashing the keyboard, but almost as easily type "john.doe@example.com" - whilst an honest user could well have "psw4235@company.com" as their real address) could just as well be put into email verification, or into an approach that did not require email addresses at all.